# Ionic 3 TypeScript Error - Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new Ionic and was trying a tutorial when I got an error `TypeScript Error - Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'`.

Its a simple ionic application to save notes. The notes are saved into ionic storage.

The code below is my service page code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage  } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Note  } from '../../models/note.model';
@Injectable()
export class NoteService {
  private notes: Note[] = [];
  private note: Note;
  constructor(public storage: Storage) {

  }
  saveNote(note: Note){
    note.created_at = Date.now();
    this.notes.push(note);
    this.storage.set('notes', this.notes);
  }
  getAllNotes(){
    return this.storage.get('notes').then(
        (notes) => {
            this.notes = notes == null ? [] : notes;
            return [...this.notes];
        }   
    )
  }
  deleteNote(created_at: number){
    this.notes = this.notes.filter((note) => {
        return note.created_at !== created_at
    })
    this.storage.set('notes', this.notes);
  }
  getNote(created_at: number){
    this.storage.get('notes').then((notes) => {
        this.note = [...notes].find(r => r.created_at === created_at);
        return this.note;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

The code below is my home.ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AddNotePage } from '../add-note/add-note';
import { NoteService } from '../../providers/note-service/note-service';
import { Note  } from '../../models/note.model';
import { ViewNotePage } from '../view-note/view-note';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  private notes: Promise<Note[]>;
  private note: Note;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private noteService: NoteService) { }
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.notes = this.getAllNotes();
  }
  addNote(){
    this.navCtrl.push(AddNotePage);
  }
  getNote(created_at: number){
    this.noteService.getNote(created_at).then((n) => {
      this.note = n;
      this.navCtrl.push(ViewNotePage, { note: this.note });
    });
  }
  getAllNotes(){
    return this.noteService.getAllNotes();
  }
}
```

[Here is the error displayed on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJiJ3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be other thing, your function inside data service returns object not the promise, so you receive data itself, so no then then :)

In your home.ts

```
  this.note = this.noteService.getNote(created_at);
  ///...nav ctrl push
```

But there's a risk of pushing before getting note, without note it will lead to error. So you could change your function inside service to return promise, then, the `then` would be correct syntax.

```
getNote(created_at: number){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.storage.get('notes').then((notes) => {
        this.note = [...notes].find(r => r.created_at === created_at);
        resolve((this.note as any).data),
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
reject((error as any).error)
    });
}, error => reject((error as any).error)
  }
```

Comment: I did exactly this but i new error kind of popped up in my main.ts file. The error is Type '{}' is not assignable to type Note. The Note in this context is the model. Following the tutorial i was working with a model was created and it looked like this...
`export interface Note {  
 title: string
 content: string
 date: Date
 created_at: number
}`

Comment: so maybe declare note an object   `private note: Note= {};`

Answer (score 1):

`NoteService.getNote` is not returning a value.

Maybe try this:

```
getNote(created_at: number){
  return this.noteService.getNote(created_at).then((n) => {
    this.note = n;
    this.navCtrl.push(ViewNotePage, { note: this.note });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it still gave the same error